# Querying sqlite3 table based on inferring another column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 table `table_name` with columns `start, end, id, val_end` and note that `val_end` is not a nullable column. Suppose there's a value `val_start` such that `val_start` for a row is the `val_end` for the previous row, e.g.,

```
start end  id val_end            val_start (doesn't actually exist in the table)
0     10   0  10.1               0
10    20   0  10.3               10.1
```

I want to query the table for `val_start` at where `end=input_time` based on manipulating `val_end`.

I tried this query:

```
  query = """
    select b.id, b.val_end as val_start
    from table_name b
    join table_name a
    on a.start = b.end
    and a.id = b.id
    WHERE a.end = :input
  """
  connector.cursor().execute(query, {"input": input_time}).fetchall()
```

But it keeps returning empty results even though there are valid columns and rows. Is there something wrong with my query?

Example, suppose `input_time=20`, the query should give:

```
[(0, 10.1)]
```

(I don't care about the format, but usually sql reads give me a list of tuples)

Here's a specific example (note I simplified the example to debug) where it seems to be failing

```
start            id      end                 val_end
20230905160000   1       20230906080000      10.1
20230905160000   2       20230906080000      10.3
```

```
  query = """
    select b.id, b.val_end as val_start
    from table_name b
    join table_name a
    on (a.start = b.end
    and a.id = b.id)
  """
  print(connector.cursor().execute(query).fetchall())
```

produces

```
[]
```

Example with original query:

```
  query = """
    select b.id, b.val_end as val_start
    from table_name b
    join table_name a
    on a.start = b.end
    and a.id = b.id
    WHERE a.end = :input
  """
  connector.cursor().execute(query, {"input": 20230906080000}).fetchall()
```

should return:

```
[(1, 0,)
 (2, 0,)
]
```

but it returns

```
[]
```

Comment: How do you know what it's returning? You never call `fetchall()`.

Comment: `{input: input_time}` This can't work, because `input` is not in quotes.  (I suppose it technically will work, but it will use the buit-in function `input()`, which is certainly not what you wanted...)

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: @Barmar That was a typo on my part. I do have `fetchall()` in my actual code

Comment: sqllite understands window function https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html

Comment: I just tried this and I got the expected result.

Comment: @Barmar hmm I can't seem to reproduce on a simplified example either. It seems it might be an issue in the codebase I am working in

Comment: @nbk What window function would you use for this?

Comment: LAG will do the trick

Comment: @nbk How does `LAG()` find the row that's related by `row1.start = row2.end`? It's for finding the previous rows in an ordered relationship.

Comment: @Barmer is has an id for partioning and val_end to sort.

Comment: @Barmar I just edited in an example in the OP where it fails

Comment: Your example is missing the `id` column.

Comment: @nbk There's no indication that `val_end` is sorted. This could be any parent-child relationship.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, edited it in

Comment: The IDs are different. Your query only works when the IDs are the same.

Comment: If it should work with different IDs, get rid of `and a.id = b.id`.

Comment: @Barmar hmm it should work with different IDs, but the query should be grouped by the id, so if I remove `and a.id = b.id`, wouldn't that remove the grouping?

Comment: What is "the id" if the IDs can be different? And why does the second example not have `where a.end = :input`?

Comment: @Barmar In the second example, I was just trying to simplify the query to debug the issue. As for the id, each row has a distinct set of `(start, end, id)`. For each `id`, we usually have multiple `(start, end)` pairs. The `val_start` for current row being the same as `val_end` for the previous row only applies within each `id` grouping. does that make sense?

Comment: But in your example, they're in a different id group, so there shouldn't be any result.

Comment: @Barmar Hmm, so I'm really not good with sql. In the latest edit, I provided an example with the original query and what the expected output. Both `id` should have `0` for `val_start`.

Comment: @Barmar The result should provide a mapping from `id` to `val_start` at the required time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255680/discussion-between-barmar-and-24n8).